# How to block all website

Tags: browser

How to block all website on the basis of top level domain name in ubuntu 14 . For example I want to block all website on my system ending with ".info" or ".org " or " ".cn " .

Comment: wild cards won't work in /etc/hosts. Kindly refer to the linked question.